# Not able to output to file in the Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

In the following code, I need to take the path and size of folder and subfolders into a file. But when the loop runs for the second time, path and size are not getting printed to the file. size.txt only contains the path and size of the 1st folder. Please somebody help me.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET xsummary=
SET xsize=

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=C" %%i IN ('"dir /s /-c /a | find "Directory""') do (echo    C%%j >> abcd.txt)
for /f "tokens=*" %%q IN (abcd.txt) do (
cd "%%q"
For /F "tokens=*" %%h IN ('"dir /s /-c /a | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do Set    xsummary=%%h
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("!xsummary!") do set xsize=%%b
Set xsize=!xsize:bytes=!
Set xsize=!xsize: =!
echo.%%q >> size.txt
echo.!xsize! >> size.txt
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `cd` — you are creating a two-line `size.txt` file in each directory.  Try

```
for ... %%h in ('"dir /s /-c /a  %%q  | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') ...
```

and remove the `cd`.

By the way, do you realize that you are getting cumulative totals?  For example, if your directory structure looks like

```
a   100K
a\b 200K
a\c 400K
```

then your result will say

```
a
700000
a\b
200000
a\c
400000
```

That’s because the second `dir` has the `/s` option.  That’s fine if that’s what you want; I just thought it might have been an oversight.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I forgot about that "cd" cammand. Your method worked with a little change. I included as "%%q" to include the folders whose names has spaces. And Yes I need the cumulative result only. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Sachin: And thanks for reminding me about quotes.  I’m a Unix person first, and I quote variables in shell scripts reflexively, but I keep forgetting to do it in DOS.  Um, I mean the Windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage it, avoid this mess by grabbing the [Sysinternals du](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) utility and running `du -v <directoryname>`. Output will be kilobytes. The `-v` option means output the size of all subdirectories.

---

With your current script, the problem seems to be appending text while in a loop. An easy workaround is to output to the command prompt window, like so:

```
echo %%q
echo !xsize!
```

and when you run the batch file, sent its output to a text file: `test.bat > size.txt`

---

A quick tip: the first bit can be simplified with:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%q in ('dir /a:d /s /b') do (
    cd "%%q"
    ...
    echo !xsize!
)
```

Basically, it's replacing the use of `find` with the `/a:d` option (list directories only) and `/b` (use bare format, no heading or summary). This also gets rid of the temporary file.

---

Modified version to work on folders with exclamation marks in the name. Using Scott's answer. See comments below.

Note that `REM` means it's a comment.

```
@echo off

REM clear the file
type NUL > size.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%q IN ('dir /a:d /s /b') do (
    echo %%q >> size.txt
    REM Run :getsize, passing "%%q" including quotes as the first parameter
    call :getsize "%%q" >> size.txt
)

REM go to the end of the file, i.e. exit
goto :eof

:getsize
REM %1 is the  first parameter. It should already be quoted.
for /f "tokens=*" %%h IN ('"dir /s /-c /a %1 | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do set xsummary=%%h
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%xsummary%") do set xsize=%%b
set xsize=%xsize:bytes=%
set xsize=%xsize: =%
echo %xsize%

goto :eof
```

---

An alternative is to use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0; $_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum; $_} | Sort-Object DirSize -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 FullName,DirSize | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File 'sizes.txt';
```

This is overly complex for the purpose of being as complete as possible - also, most of those commands have shorter aliases; this is just more readable. And if you separate certain sections out into functions/their own line, it becomes much more readable and possibly shorter.

Expanding it:

- `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`

  Recursively list all subdirectories and files
- `?{ $_.PSIsContainer }`

  Filter so only directories are kept (`?` is an alias for `Where-Object`). `$_` refers to the object(s) piped to this - since `Get-ChildItem` passes a list/array of objects, this processes them one at a time.
- `%{$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0; $_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum; $_}`

  Calculate size of each directory (`%` is an alias for `Foreach-Object`, so run what is between `{ }` on each individual object. Each object is a directory, as per the previous parts.)

  Expanding it:

  - `$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0;`

    A semicolon (`;`) denotes the end of a line/statement, and does not pass the output on, as opposed to a pipe (`|`). This particular bit has no output, and it's just adding the `DirSize` property to the directory object and initialising it to 0. This is done for easier filtering and neater output later.
  - `$_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum;`

    Set `DirSize` to the `Sum` property of the output of that command. `$()` means execute what is inside the parentheses and substitute that in.

    Expanding it:

    - `Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname`

      Get all the contents of the current directory object (`$_`, `Fullname` just means the full path). `-Recurse` means count the contents of subdirectories as well.
    - `?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer }`

      Filter so only files are kept. Directories have a `Length` property of 0, so we need to use sum the files within - essentially what your batch script does, except we're dealing with actual numbers, objects and properties instead of grabbing a 'number' as text using `find`.
    - `Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length`

      Calculate the sum of all the `Length` properties passed to it. This returns an object containing the property `Sum`, which is used above (`.Sum`)
  - `$_`

  Essentially `echo`ing the object to pass it on to the next section. It now has a `DirSize` property.
- `Sort-Object DirSize -Descending`

  Sort descending by `DirSize`
- `Select-Object -First 10 FullName,DirSize`

  Only output the first 10, and only the name and size
- `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File 'sizes.txt';`

  Output to `sizes.txt`. The `Format-Table` and `Out-String` bits are to prevent truncating to console window width (normally 80 characters). 4096 should be more than enough characters for any Windows path and directory size, considering a Windows path is typically limited to 255 characters (IIRC). The `AutoSize` just means make it as short as possible without truncating, instead of padding with a whole lot of whitespace to fit 4096 characters.

And the command as a one liner to run in `cmd.exe` (you can run the above version within PowerShell):

```
powershell -c "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0; $_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum; $_} | Sort-Object DirSize -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 FullName,DirSize | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File 'sizes.txt';"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip. It really resolved a lot of complexities.

Comment: "dir /a:d /s /b" this cammand is removing special characters from the path of the directory. I need the exact path. Can u help me?

Comment: @Sachin What are those special characters? Could you provide an example path that this affects?

Comment: original path: D:\Songs\Audio\Hindi\Wake Up S!d and it changed to D:\Songs\Audio\Hindi\Wake Up Sd

Comment: @Sachin This problem isn't due to the `dir` command - your original would do the same thing. The problem is because of `EnableDelayedExpansion`. `cmd` first parses a line in a batch file to figure out what it should do, and normally expands variables at this time (`%variablename%`). Then it executes the line. `EnableDelayedExpansion` means expand variables in exclamation marks (`!variablename!`) at execution time. What's happening here is the variable `%%q` is being expanded at parse time and then `cmd` is choking on the `!` at execution time.

Comment: @Sachin BTW, a whole `for` loop until the `)` is considered one line. That is why you need delayed expansion if variables change within a loop.

Comment: @Sachin I've appended a fixed version to my answer. Instead of using delayed expansion, it uses a call to a 'subroutine' to calculate the size. The `call` in this case basically means 'start a new command process and `goto` this label, passing in this parameter, and wait for it to finish'. By passing the folder as a parameter, we don't have to worry about changing variables within a loop since the subroutine is essentially another process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need delayed expansion as after this code I need to append one more code to get the 3 no. of biggest folders.

Comment: @Sachin You could enable delayed expansion after this (put other code just above the first `goto :eof`), but if your other code needs to process the same folder names, you will run into the same problem. I would recommend using PowerShell (as you mentioned in another question, you are also having trouble comparing folders over 4 GB). Otherwise, you could do something similar to this, with the `call` command. What are you trying to do? There might be an easier way. You can get a nice graphical representation of the biggest folders with a tool like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/).

Comment: I am trying to find some number of biggest folders/subfolders in a particular drive.

Comment: @Sachin Give WinDirStat a try, unless it must be through the command line. In that case, I would heavily recommend PowerShell. Here's a one-liner in PowerShell to show the top 10 biggest (sub)folders: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0; $_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum; $_} | Sort-Object DirSize -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 FullName,DirSize;` Size only counts the files in the folder, not its subfolders, same as your script.

Comment: Thanks Bob for this but I need to run the script through the cammand line.

Comment: my script counts the size of the subfolders also in the parent folder's size.

Comment: @Sachin If you are on Windows Vista or later, you can run this directly in the command line: `powershell -c "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DirSize -Value 0; $_.DirSize = $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.Fullname | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum; $_} | Sort-Object DirSize -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 FullName,DirSize | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File 'sizes.txt';"` This version counts subfolder sizes and outputs to `sizes.txt`.

Comment: Ultimately you are using powershell. I have to run the script on the server which runs of Windows XP machine.

Comment: Looks like I can't work with command prompt only.I have tried various methods but they are very time consuming. So moving to powershell. Can u please tell me what your above powershell code is doing?

Comment: @Sachin Added explanation to answer.